# JPA query not returning updated results in list

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, guice

I have an issue with a webapp running in tomcat where I have an abstract DAO class with a method called all() which returns all entities from the database or JPA cache. It seems to correctly return the entities on the initial call but subsequent calls don't reflect updates happening from separate UI calls which will use the entity managers find method to find the specific entity from the list, update the relative fields and commit that. When I view that list via the same all() method later I still see the original values. If I make another update in the logs I can see the value changing from the correct value(not the original value) to the updated value and the logs shows those updates happening correctly each time.

I'm using guice for injection. I've played around with the logging and can see the same hashcode on the entity manager being used throughout a request but different for each request. I've played with the following the persistance.xml file which didn't seem to help either...

```
    <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

I can't see why my all() won't return updated results, I've also tried adding code to find the specific entity I'm updating in the list then replaced it by calling the following...

```
entity = em.find(Class.class, id)
```

This seemed to fix the issue on that particular entity so it appears my query is reusing old.

Here's a snippet from my DAO class

```
private final Provider<EntityManager> emP;

protected EntityManager em(boolean useTransaction) throws DaoException {
    return useTransaction ? begin() : emP.get();
}

public List<T> all() throws DaoException {
    EntityManager em = em(false);
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(eClass);
    Root<T> from = cq.from(eClass);
    return em.createQuery(cq.select(from)).getResultList();
}

public T save(T t) throws DaoException {
    return save(t, em(true));
}

protected T save(T t, EntityManager em) throws DaoException {
    if (Objects.isNull(t)) {
        throw new DaoException("can't save null object: " + getDaoClass(), new NullPointerException());
    }

    T saved;
    if (t.getId() > 0) {
        saved = em.merge(t);
    } else {
        em.persist(t);
        saved = t;
    }

    autoCommit();
    return saved;
}

protected void autoCommit() throws DaoException {
    if (autoCommit) {
        commit();
    }
}

public void commit() throws DaoException {
    EntityManager em = emP.get();
    if (!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        throw new DaoException("transaction isn't active, unable to commit");
    }

    try {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        throw new DaoException("transaction not active", e);
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        throw new DaoException("commit rolled back", e);
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering if anyone has any insights on why this might be happening or have any suggestions on what else I can try to check?

Comment: Your emP probably always returns the same em, which returns results from its first-level cache. Stop thinking that you can use JPA without transactions, and keep an EM open for a long time. You can't. Always get a new EM, start a transaction, do what you need to do (read and/or write), commit.

Comment: I will try this now

Comment: I changed the EntityManager em(boolean useTransaction) method to ignore the useTransaction boolean and just begin the transaction and then added a commit to the end of my all() method but it still produced the same results. Also I'm not keeping it opening, i'm using guice to inject the entity manager which should new for each request using guices UnitOfWork

Comment: Code for `emP`? How is it injected? Is the `final` modifier for `emP` essential?

Comment: Turn on eclipseLink logging, which will show the session being used underneath the EntityManager. Most containers use wrappers over injected resources so they can more easily manage the lifecycles, so the hashcode you see might be for the wrapper, not the EntityManager implementation doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the cause of the issue I was having. I was using the ElementCollection annotation in my entities when referencing lists. I removed the annotation and replaced it with a JoinTable and OneToMany annotations and things are working correctly.

The issue I had was that the entity would be stored in the database fine and I was updating that entity as expected but JPA had embedded the list of entities where it was referenced.

So I was seeing the embedded list returned each time which was not the actual entity I had updated. My entities are now using proper join tables instead of embedded objects and everything is behaving as expected.